# Select columns by multiple partial string match from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the df with following columns:

```
df.columns

['total_rech_num_6', 'total_rech_num_7', 'total_rech_num_8','max_rech_amt_6', 'max_rech_amt_7', 'max_rech_amt_8','max_amt_6', 'max_amt_7', 'max_amt_8'].
```

I would like to select only those columns which has 'rech' AND '6' in the column name.

I tried this to select columns with'rech':

```
recharge_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'rech' in col]
```

But i dont kow how to add the other string condition to get the 'rech' AND '6' columns. Need help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this 1 line expression:

```
   recharge_cols = [i for i in list(df) if 'rech' in i and '6' in i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `and` with another `in` statement:

```
recharge_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'rech' in col and '6' in col]
print (recharge_cols)
['total_rech_num_6', 'max_rech_amt_6']
```

Pandas solution:

```
recharge_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('rech') & 
                           df.columns.str.contains('6')].tolist()

print (recharge_cols)
['total_rech_num_6', 'max_rech_amt_6']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
recharge_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'rech' in col and '6' in col]
```